# TYPO3 extbase RTE parse function

Tags: typo3, rte

TYPO3 6.1

How do I use RTE parse function in an extbase extension?
I am calling the action through ajax and in that action I am getting rte content using a query.
Later I am returning that row like this

```
$bodytext = $row['bodytext'];
return json_encode($bodytext);
```

Here I am not outputting this to any fluid template.

So how to parse this `$bodytext` in RTE parse function, so that I can get richtext output?

Comment: I got it working.
 $lCobj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
$lCobj->parseFunc($bodytext , array(), '< lib.parseFunc_RTE');

Comment: The question is: Why don't you use a fluid template in the first place? It is capable of rendering json/text output as well, so you created your problem by cutting corners in the first place.

Comment: If, for example, you use any form of Javascript Templating (like AngularJS), you need the parsed output in your JSON, because it is not possible to render it with Fluid as the final html gets generated by Javascript.